# Updating Z values on points using UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, z-value

I have created the following script, which moves the points from my_input_points_fc to my_output_points_fc by user input
Furthermore, the z-values in my_output_points_fc should also be updated. However, after executing the script I get zero values in the my_output_pointy_fc under the height_field.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
arcpy.env.workspace = "my_path"
inputFC = "my_input_points_fc"
outputFC = "my_output_points_fc"
xValue = -1
yValue = -1
while xValue == -1:
    try:
        xOffset = input("Please enter the X coordinate by which the point should be move: ")
        xValue = float(xOffset)
    except Exception:
        print()
        print("The entry was not correct! Please try again")
while yValue == -1:
    try:
        yOffset = input("Please enter the Y coordinate by which the point should move ")
        yValue = float(yOffset)
    except Exception:
        print()
        print("The entry was not correct! Please try again")
spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(inputFC).spatialReference
arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(arcpy.env.workspace, outputFC, "POINT",inputFC, has_z = "ENABLED", spatial_reference= spatialRef)
cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputFC, ("SHAPE@XYZ"))
cur2 = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputFC, ("SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y", "height_field"))
for row in cur2:
    insert_row = (row[0] + xValue, row[1] + yValue, row[2])
    cur.insertRow([insert_row])
print ("Points have been moved")
del cur
del cur2
del row
```

Comment: Isnt the tool named `arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management`, dont know if it matters. You are not calculating the "height_field". You are only using the values to set Z. Change `cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputFC, ("SHAPE@XYZ"))` to `cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputFC, ["SHAPE@XYZ", "height_field"])` and modify `insert_row` row

Comment: I think you should remove your try/except statements while testing because that can mask otherwise useful error messages.

Comment: I need the input values in order to shift the points to a new position

Comment: @BERA I am not sure how to modify the insert_row. I get following message: TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if I correctly understand what you are trying to do:

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputFC, ("SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y", "SHAPE@Z", "height_field")) as ic:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputFC, ("SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y", "height_field")) as sc:
        for row in sc:
            ic.insertRow((row[0] + xValue, row[1] + yValue, row[2], row[2]))
```

Comment: thank you Dan, it worked!